# PHP - error_get_last method for warnings?

Tags: php

I am using [`unlink`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php) on my PHP page. In some situations, Permission may be denied for deleting the directory. Instead of having

`Warning: unlink(stuff/New folder) [function.unlink]: Permission denied in ... on line 30`

show up on the rendered page, is there a way for me to do a "warning_get_last" that will capture the last given warning, so I can output it nicely? Or does `error_get_last` include these?

I know I can suppress the warnings with `@unlink` and that I can also check to see if `unlink` returns false, but I would like to know the error message that goes along with it *if* it does fail.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `error_reporting(0)` to not show the warning or any errors in the rendered page. It will still show up in your server error logs and you can still use `error_get_last()` to get the last error.

You can test it out with this:

```
error_reporting(0);
unlink('some file that does not exist'); // generates a warning
print_r(error_get_last());
```

EDITED: Please note that `error_reporting(0)` will affect subsequent code, so you'll want to set it back to the level you want after you're through the code where you want to suppress the error display.

Comment: `error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING)` - will cause the error_get_last to display errors or warnings? I can use @ to stop the warnings from showing up. I just need a way to get the message from them.

Comment: I've updated the answer, but do let me know if I'm just misunderstanding the question or something.

Comment: Got the job done! The warnings are showing up with `error_get_last`. Thanks!

Comment: `error_reporting(0)`: NEVER turn it off! Use `ini_set('display_errors', 0);` instead

Answer (score 1):

You write set your own error handler, enable it just before the call, and revert back to normal afterwards.

Use [set-error-handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) to turn on the error handler, save to a global variable (that's the simplest - perhaps not most "correct") and show if there was an error. Or user error_get_last() (as suggeted by Trott).

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline) {
    global $lastErrorString;
    $lastErrorString = $errstr;
    return false;
}

// Calling function:
global $lastErrorString;
$lastErrorString=false;
$old_error_handler = set_error_handler("myErrorHandler");
unlink($file);
restore_error_handler();
if ($lastErrorString !== false) {
    echo 'Went wrong: ' . $lastErrorString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see why the following is any worse than the 2 other proposals; in fact I'd say it's better because it's shorter than Robbie's answer and doesn't have a global effect unlike Trott's answer:

```
$ok = @unlink(...);
if ($ok === FALSE)
    throw new Exception(error_get_last()['message']);
```

Output when run:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'unlink(foobar.txt): No such file or directory' in /Users/erik/code/test.php:5
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /Users/erik/code/test.php on line 5
```